# Set value in codebehind from XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got following variable in my `xaml.cs`:

```
bool _isdragging = false;
```

Now I wanna set the value of `_isdragging` from my `xaml` code below:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="true">
        <!--set _isdragging to true-->
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="false">
        <!--set _isdragging to false-->
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

How can I achieve this? How can this be done in `xaml`/`wpf`?
I've only found articles about getting/binding the value (to a control) but none handles setting it...

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No you have a field, not a proprty.
You can use setters like this:

```
<Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="IsDragging" Value="True" />
</Trigger>
```

But IsDragging should be a [dependency property](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140620/WPF-Tutorial-Dependency-Property) of your control

You can use binding in setters:

```
<Setter Property="IsDragging" 
    Value="{Binding AnotherProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

**Update**

For your scenario you can use workaround to access simple public field from another control. Add Behaviour class and bind to its value:

```
<Setter Property="behaviours:IsDraggingBehaviour.IsDragging" Value="True"/>
```

And then in your Behaviour class:

```
public static class IsDraggingBehaviour
{
    public static bool GetSelectAll(YourControl target)
    {
        return (bool)target.GetValue(IsDraggingAttachedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSelectAll(YourControl target, bool value)
    {
        target.SetValue(IsDraggingAttachedProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDraggingAttachedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsDragging", typeof(bool), typeof(YourControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnSelectIsDraggingPropertyChanged));

    static void OnSelectIsDraggingPropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = (YourControl) o;
        //control.AccessYourProperty = true; change your value here
    }
}
```

But I think that there is a better way to solve your issue by change composition or use WPF features (like dependency property and clear bindings). You may try to extend your question.

Comment: I don't wanna set the dependency property value (it is already `true` or `false`) -- I wanna set the `value` of my variable called `isdragging` which I obviously included on top of the question...

Comment: @cramopy 0. It is not a property. 1. What .cs file do you mean? Is it YourControl.xaml.cs or DataContext or other class? 2. Is this control template writes to YourControl.xaml or other control inside it?

Comment: it is my `xaml.cs`-file. and i wanna access it from the parent `.xaml` control....

Comment: @cramopy i updated my answer. If YourControl is a parent object you can find child by name.